# Specify times and dates in Pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, dateplot

I have x-data as dates associated with float values; plotting them with pgfplots is as easy as

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
  date coordinates in=x,
  xticklabel style={rotate=90,anchor=near xticklabel},
  xticklabel=\year-\month-\day
]
\addplot table [red] {%
  2016-10-10 50
  2016-10-11 56
};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now, I have dates *plus times*. Simply adding them to the table obviously results in a failed compilation

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
  date coordinates in=x,
  xticklabel style={rotate=90,anchor=near xticklabel},
  xticklabel=\year-\month-\day
]
\addplot table [red] {%
  2016-10-10 13:10 50
  2016-10-11 12:55 56
};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '12:55' as a floating 
point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near ':55'..
```

How to specify times then?

Comment: Are you looking for https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445564/121799 ?

Comment: @marmot It should be much easier than that; Pgfplot *does* support times after all.

Comment: Yes, but you have to help pgfplots then to judge whether a space separates the time  from the day or a column.

Comment: @marmot Indeed. I wouldn't mind adding commas with a `col sep`, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have any problems after adding a comma. Since you added the option `red` to the table: where did you add `col sep=comma` and `header=false`? At least this works:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
  date coordinates in=x,
  xticklabel style={rotate=90,anchor=near xticklabel},
  xmin=2016-10-10 00:00,
  xmax=2016-10-12 00:00,
  xticklabel=\year-\month-\day
]
\addplot[only marks] table [col sep=comma,header=false] {%
  2016-10-10 13:10,50
  2016-10-11 12:55,56
};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, I'd been missing `header=false`.