# pgfplots: How to add names of the days of the week to dateplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis, domain, dateplot

Assumed we have the following code:

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
    Date;                   Value
    2019-04-01 12:00:00;    1
    2019-04-02 12:00:00;    2
    2019-04-03 12:00:00;    3
    2019-04-04 12:00:00;    4
    2019-04-05 12:00:00;    5
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[date coordinates in = x,
                     xmin                = 2019-04-02 12:00:00,
                     xticklabel          = \month-\day,
                     table/col sep       = semicolon]
                     \addplot table[x=Date,y=Value]{data.csv};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Question:**

- How can I replace the current `numeric dates` with `weekdays names` like *Mon.*, *Tue.*, *Wed.*, *Thu.*, *Fri.*, *Sat.*, *Sun.*?
- Is there an option available so `pgfplots` can calculate the corresponding `names of the days of the week` for each `numeric date` automatically by itself?

I want to avoid setting `xtick labels = {Mon., Tue., Wed., ...}` manually by hand for each `tick`.

Comment: Like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20447/121799)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you can use the macros provided by the `pgfcalendar` package to convert `\year-\month-\day` to Julian days (`\pgfcalendardatetojulian`), then to day of week (`\pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday`) and then print the corresponding weekday (`\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname`), all directly in `xticklabel`:

```
xticklabel          = \pgfcalendardatetojulian{\year-\month-\day}{\tmpCnt}\pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\tmpCnt}{\tmpCnt}\pgfcalendarweekdayname{\tmpCnt},
```

`\newcnt\tmpCnt` is required first.

I suggest also adding `xtick distance=1` so you get just one tick per day.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
    Date;                   Value
    2019-04-01 12:00:00;    1
    2019-04-02 12:00:00;    2
    2019-04-03 12:00:00;    3
    2019-04-04 12:00:00;    4
    2019-04-05 12:00:00;    5
\end{filecontents}
\newcount\tmpCnt
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[date coordinates in = x,
                     xmin                = 2019-04-02 12:00:00,
                     xticklabel          = \pgfcalendardatetojulian{\year-\month-\day}{\tmpCnt}\pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\tmpCnt}{\tmpCnt}\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname{\tmpCnt},
                     xtick distance      = 1,
                     table/col sep       = semicolon]
                     \addplot table[x=Date,y=Value]{data.csv};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]