# Counter does not work properly in \pgfmathparse

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfmathparse

I have this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\newcounter{cheat}


\definecolor{trolleygrey}{rgb}{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}
\definecolor{darkgray}{rgb}{0.66, 0.66, 0.66}

\title{pgfplots}
\author{antonis.makris2411 Mak}
\date{July 2019}



\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{figure*}[!htbp]
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/bar shift auto/.style={
        /pgf/bar shift={
        -0.5*(int(3/2*\numplotsofactualtype-1)*\pgfplotbarwidth 
        + (int(3/2*\numplotsofactualtype-1))*(#1))  +
          (.5+\plotnumofactualtype+int(\plotnumofactualtype/2))*\pgfplotbarwidth 
          + \plotnumofactualtype*(#1)
        },
    },
    A bar/.style={nodes near coords={\stepcounter{cheat}%
    \pgfmathparse{pow(10,int((1+\number\value{cheat})/2))}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult},
      style={trolleygrey,fill=trolleygrey,mark=none},postaction={pattern=crosshatch
    dots}},
    B bar/.style={darkgray,fill=darkgray,mark=none}
}  
    \begin{axis}[
        width  = 1.2*\textwidth,
        major x tick style = transparent,
        ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
        bar width=0.4cm,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        ylabel = {Response Time (sec)},
        symbolic x coords={P1,P2,P3},
        xtick = data,
        scaled y ticks = false,
        enlarge x limits=0.35,
        x tick label style={font=\Large,yshift=-10pt},
        y tick label style={font=\Large},
        y label style={font=\Large},
        ymin=0,
        legend cell align=left,
        legend style={font=\Large,draw=none, legend columns=-1},
        visualization depends on=y \as \rawy,
        every node near coord/.append style={
                    anchor=north,xshift=0.2cm,
                    shift={(axis direction cs:P1,-\rawy)}
                }       
       ]
        \addplot[A bar]
            coordinates {(P1, 104.09) (P2,685.37) (P3,685.37)};
        \addplot[B bar]
            coordinates {(P1, 103.43) (P2,364.37) (P3,685.37)};

        \addplot[A bar]
              coordinates {(P1,495.74) (P2,454.20) (P3,685.37)};
        \addplot[B bar]
            coordinates {(P1, 364.43) (P2,364.37) (P3,685.37)};

        \addplot[A bar]
           coordinates {(P1,1929.74) (P2,454.20) (P3,685.37)};
        \addplot[B bar]
              coordinates {(P1,699.54) (P2,454.20) (P3,685.37)};

        \legend{S1, S2}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}% pic 1
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

that procuces this:

[image]

The problem here is the values of x coords. As it is illustrated in above image, in P1 I have 10 100 10000, in P2 10 1000 10000 and in P3 100 1000 16384. **I want to add a fix number on those values i.e. 10 100 1000 in P1,P2,P3.** I understand the problem is somewhere in this code:

```
 A bar/.style={nodes near coords={\stepcounter{cheat}%
    \pgfmathparse{pow(10,int((1+\number\value{cheat})/2))}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult},
      style={trolleygrey,fill=trolleygrey,mark=none},postaction={pattern=crosshatch
    dots}},
    B bar/.style={darkgray,fill=darkgray,mark=none}
```

maybe here: `\pgfmathparse{pow(10,int((1+\number\value{cheat})/2))}`

but I do not know hot to fix this. Does anyone has an idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a semi-automatic solution which requires to manually set the number of categories (here P1, P2, P3, so three categories).

It uses an array with the bar labels (source: [Abbreviated month names as tick labels in PGFplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20445/abbreviated-month-names-as-tick-labels-in-pgfplots)) which is accessed using the `cheat` counter. The counter is increased every time an `A bar` coordinate is plotted.

The `A bar` data is processed in parallel, so the `P1` coordinates correspond to counter values 0,1,2, the `P2` coordinates to 3,4,5 and the `P3` coordinates to 6,7,8. Therefore if you divide by the number of categories (here 3) and floor the result you get the correct array index numbers 0,1,2 for X coordinate `P1`, `P2`, `P3` respectively.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\newcounter{cheat}

\definecolor{trolleygrey}{rgb}{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}
\definecolor{darkgray}{rgb}{0.66, 0.66, 0.66}

\begin{document}
\def\sublabels{{"10","100","10,000"}}
\begin{figure*}[!htbp]
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/bar shift auto/.style={
        /pgf/bar shift={
        -0.5*(int(3/2*\numplotsofactualtype-1)*\pgfplotbarwidth 
        + (int(3/2*\numplotsofactualtype-1))*(#1))  +
          (.5+\plotnumofactualtype+int(\plotnumofactualtype/2))*\pgfplotbarwidth 
          + \plotnumofactualtype*(#1)
        },
    },
    A bar/.style={nodes near coords={%
    \pgfmathparse{\sublabels[floor(\number\value{cheat}/3)]}%
    \pgfmathresult%
    \stepcounter{cheat}%
    },
    style={trolleygrey,fill=trolleygrey,mark=none},
    postaction={pattern=crosshatch dots},
    },
    B bar/.style={darkgray,fill=darkgray,mark=none}
}  
    \begin{axis}[
        width  = 1.2*\textwidth,
        major x tick style = transparent,
        ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
        bar width=0.4cm,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        ylabel = {Response Time (sec)},
        symbolic x coords={P1,P2,P3},
        xtick = data,
        scaled y ticks = false,
        enlarge x limits=0.35,
        x tick label style={font=\Large,yshift=-10pt},
        y tick label style={font=\Large},
        y label style={font=\Large},
        ymin=0,
        legend cell align=left,
        legend style={font=\Large,draw=none, legend columns=-1},
        visualization depends on=y \as \rawy,
        every node near coord/.append style={
                    anchor=north,xshift=0.2cm,
                    shift={(axis direction cs:P1,-\rawy)}
                }       
       ]
        \addplot[A bar]
            coordinates {(P1, 104.09) (P2,685.37) (P3,685.37)};
        \addplot[B bar]
            coordinates {(P1, 103.43) (P2,364.37) (P3,685.37)};

        \addplot[A bar]
            coordinates {(P1,495.74) (P2,454.20) (P3,685.37)};
        \addplot[B bar]
            coordinates {(P1, 364.43) (P2,364.37) (P3,685.37)};

        \addplot[A bar]
            coordinates {(P1,1929.74) (P2,454.20) (P3,685.37)};
        \addplot[B bar]
            coordinates {(P1,699.54) (P2,454.20) (P3,685.37)};

        \legend{S1, S2}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}% pic 1
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It workes.