# How to plot date axis with pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, dateplot

I have the following code, which builds in part off the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20445/abbreviated-month-names-as-tick-labels-in-pgfplots).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

%colors
\usepackage{color} % colors
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{colourone}{RGB}{22,131,198}
\definecolor{colourtwo}{RGB}{202,211,43}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
date,vix
2017-01-01,13.0875
2017-01-08,11.9225
2017-01-15,11.416
2017-01-22,12.1675
2017-01-29,10.972
2017-02-05,11.716
2017-02-12,11.168
2017-02-19,11.406
2017-02-26,11.6225
2017-03-05,12.064
2017-03-12,11.702
2017-03-19,11.554
2017-03-26,12.54
2017-04-02,11.872
2017-04-09,12.464
2017-04-16,15.2125
2017-04-23,14.558
2017-04-30,10.726
}\chartthree

\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/ybar legend/.style={
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \draw[ ##1,/tikz/.cd,yshift=-0.25em]
            (0cm,0cm) rectangle (0.6em,0.6em);},},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
x=0.5mm,
axis lines=left,
enlarge x limits={0,upper},
enlarge y limits={0.1, upper},
stack plots = y,
%
% y ticks style and label
ylabel={Index},
ytick distance = 5,
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=1, /tikz/.cd},
ymin=5,
%
% x axis ticks and style
date coordinates in=x,
%xtick=data,
xticklabels from table={\chartthree}{date}, 
xticklabel={\pgfcalendar{tickcal}{\tick}{\tick}{\pgfcalendarshorthand{\month-\year}{.}}},
x tick label style = {rotate=90},
%
% done with the axis, now the plots
\addplot [colourone, fill = colourone]
table [x=date,y=vix] from \chartthree \closedcycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The goal is for my x-axis to have the labels in the form `mm-yy` where `mm` indicates the short text form of the month (e.g. Jan, Aug) and `yy` the last two digits of the year. So the labels should be in the form Jan-20, for instance.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, I'd like to be able to define the interval distance (only every 8th date should show).

Comment: `mm` has only 2 chars but the abbreviation of months has 3 chars.

Comment: One thing that you are doing wrong is to miss a `]` after `x tick label style = {rotate=90}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, `\pgfcalendarshorthand` does not provide us with means to select only the two last digits of the year. So we need to do that ourselves.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

%colors
\definecolor{colourone}{RGB}{22,131,198}
\definecolor{colourtwo}{RGB}{202,211,43}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
date,vix
2017-01-01,13.0875
2017-01-08,11.9225
2017-01-15,11.416
2017-01-22,12.1675
2017-01-29,10.972
2017-02-05,11.716
2017-02-12,11.168
2017-02-19,11.406
2017-02-26,11.6225
2017-03-05,12.064
2017-03-12,11.702
2017-03-19,11.554
2017-03-26,12.54
2017-04-02,11.872
2017-04-09,12.464
2017-04-16,15.2125
2017-04-23,14.558
2017-04-30,10.726
}\chartthree

\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/ybar legend/.style={
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \draw[ ##1,/tikz/.cd,yshift=-0.25em]
            (0cm,0cm) rectangle (0.6em,0.6em);},},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\pft#1#2#3#4-#5-#6;{\edef\myshortyear{#3#4}}%

\begin{axis}[
x=0.5mm,
axis lines=left,
enlarge x limits={0,upper},
enlarge y limits={0.1, upper},
stack plots = y,
%
% y ticks style and label
ylabel={Index},
ytick distance = 5,
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=1, /tikz/.cd},
ymin=5,
%
% x axis ticks and style
date coordinates in=x,
%xtick=data,
xticklabels from table={\chartthree}{date}, 
xticklabel={\pgfcalendar{tickcal}{\tick}{\tick}{\pgfcalendarshorthand{m}{.}}%
\expandafter\pft\tick;%
--\myshortyear},
x tick label style = {rotate=90}]
%
% done with the axis, now the plots
\addplot [colourone, fill = colourone]
table [x=date,y=vix] from \chartthree \closedcycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you - this was perfect!